# Is it possible to use a pre-built map?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, static-map

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I apologize in advance if my question is either inaccurate, stupid, or inappropriate.

Please consider me as a newbie in ROS related subject.
I have quickly been through the navigation tutorial and if I correctly understand the logic behind the navigation stack it is possible for it to use an external map (static_map seems to be the correct name). Since my robot will evolve in a rather static environment I would like to provide it with a manually pre-built map of this environment.

1. Is it possible ?
2. If it is indeed possible how can I do it ? (see below) **Answered**
   The specifications of the map file are here:
   http://wiki.ros.org/map_server

I thank you in advance for your answers and your advice.

EDIT 2:
Link to the map we built with the corresponding yml file.
https://github.com/Bacab/SARGAS/blob/master/Maps/plan.png
https://github.com/Bacab/SARGAS/blob/master/Maps/plan.yml

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200603/is-it-possible-to-use-a-pre-built-map-?/) by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-01-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think i can't really understand what are you mean , Do you want : (1) load a 2D pre-built map to ROS map server and use this map to test robot navigation package? or (2) Simulate a 3D environment and let robot use this simulator environment to build a map then using to navigation stack .

if the situation (1) : follow @Andromeda 's answer , and i think the "arbotix" simulator and "rbx1" package which you can find in http://wiki.ros.org will help you .
(2) : can't find any tutorial already exist , but you can try to use gazebo_world_edit & ros_plugin , some tutorial link: http://gazebosim.org/tutorials ,hope it will useful ~

---

Originally posted by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) with karma: 141 on 2015-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bacab](https://answers.ros.org/users/21320/bacab/) on 2015-01-12**:
Thank you.
Your first assumption is correct (ie:"(1) load a 2D pre-built map to ROS map server and use this map to test robot navigation package.").
However it is not for tests, the final robot will use it for navigation.

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-12**:
I think may be you should use a launch file to load your map (.yaml & .pgm) to your ros map_server package then use it in navigation stack . but I am not sure , hope it can help you ~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not really sure, if I understood your question, but I share with you what I did, perhaps it helps.
I've created a pgm file using Gimp

> A1_map.pgm

with a good pixel definition.
And then I created a yaml file with the resolution, width, height, etc...

> A1_map.yaml:

```
image: A1_map.pgm
resolution: 0.01
origin: [-10, -10, 0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196 # Taken from the Willow Garage map in the turtlebot_navigation package
negate: 0
width:  20
height: 20
```

where for height and width you put the desired dimension expressed in meters. So opening the map with RViz one side of the map corresponds to 20 cells of RViz (if 1 cell has a dimension of 1 meter)

Both files are copied into the main folder of my package under

> maps/

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2015-01-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2015-01-12**:
I've managed to do the same. I teleoperated my robot on a simulated Gazebo World to build a map of the environment using the GMapping package, and then saved it using the ([map_saver tool](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server)) from the map_server package.
The problem is to load that map to navigate on it

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-12**:
@Sergio MP It's a surprise for me to find your comment , as you say you can using gazebo environment to build a map ? you already done that ? I also want to do it , but don't know how to do - - | could you help me ? thank you very much ~

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2015-01-13**:
@forinkzan Sure. What I did was to create a .world file with the workspace where I want my robot to navigate. Then, make sure to include a Hokuyo 2D laserscan or Kinect in your robot's URDF with their respective Gazebo plugin included. Spawm your robot into the Gazebo world, configure and execute

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2015-01-13**:
the gmapping node to build the map, and drive it around using your keyboard with the key_teleop.py node. Finally, if you want to save the map that gmapping just created, you can use the [map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server).
Cheers!

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-13**:
thanks very much ~
how can i drive the robot ? with a diff_drive plugin & set odom frame ? I don't know why i can't add plugin to my robot urdf file , it's always fail = =...  , are there some tutorials?

**Comment by [Sergio MP](https://answers.ros.org/users/542/sergio-mp/) on 2015-01-14**:
Jum, I see. You should check the  [Husky description package](https://github.com/husky/husky_description) for reference.
Cheers!

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-20**:
@Sergio MP  Finally i can build map in gazebo ~ , thank you very much , now i prepare to navigation in it ~

**Comment by [forinkzan](https://answers.ros.org/users/20935/forinkzan/) on 2015-01-28**:
@Sergio MP Can you load map and navigation on it now ? in gazebo ?

**Comment by [l0g1x](https://answers.ros.org/users/12831/l0g1x/) on 2015-04-08**:
@Andromeda When you say you created A1_map.pgm with "good pixel definition" what value did you go with? Does this signify/change anything?